# Where can I find this certificate to update ? "The following certificate is about to expire....CODE SIGNING CERTIFICATE.

Tags: ssl, osx-mavericks, code-signing-certificate

I am getting this email about every six minutes, day and night:

**The following certificate is about to expire on your server, server.xxxxxx.private:  Name: server.xxxxxxx.private Code Signing Certificate Expiration Date: December 14, 2013 10:13:03 PM PST**

I can't find this certificate on my server to update it. **Would anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you are using Mac OS X Mavericks Server.

Someone which faced same issue wrote an answer on his blog : [here](http://sharedmemorydump.net/post/2013-08-30-certificate-expires-soon-mac-os-x-server).